# First epoch taking taking hours all others taking 1 second

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, hyperparameters

I am trying to hyperperamter tune a hybrid lstm. I have the code run on the google cloud. However, the first epoch takes upwards of an hour to two hours to complete, whereas the second third fourth and fifth only take 1 second, I am not exaggerating, that is the actual time. Here is the code I wrote. I can't find the problem. Edit: Let me be more specific. The time after the last epoch end in trial 1 to the time the first epoch finish in trial 2. Trials, being diffrent hyperparamater configuration is an hour or two.

```py
from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2, adam_v2
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras_tuner
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
sgd = gradient_descent_v2.SGD(clipnorm=1.0)
adam = adam_v2.Adam(clipnorm=1.0)
def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(hp.Int("num_layers", 1, 5)):   
        model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(
            filters=hp.Int(f"filters{i}", min_value=32, max_value=10000, step=32),
            kernel_size=hp.Int(f"kernel_size{i}", min_value=1, max_value=15, step=1),                           
            activation=hp.Choice("activation", ["relu", "tanh","sigmoid","softmax","selu"]),
            input_shape=(None, n_steps,n_features))))
        
        model.add(Dropout(rate=hp.Float(f"rate{i}", min_value=0.01, max_value=0.26, step=0.05)))

    for i in range(hp.Int("num_max", 1, 5)):
        model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D())) 
        
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten())) 

    for i in range(hp.Int("num_layers2", 1, 5)):
        model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=hp.Int(f"units{i}", min_value=32, max_value=10000, step=32), 
                                activation=hp.Choice("activation2", ["relu", "tanh","sigmoid","softmax","selu"]),return_sequences=(True))))
        model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer= hp.Choice("optimizer",['sgd','adam']), loss="mae",metrics=['mae'])
            
    return model
        
   
tuner = keras_tuner.BayesianOptimization(
    hypermodel=build_model,
    objective='val_mae',
    max_trials=1000,
    alpha=0.0001,
    beta=2.6,
    )

print(tuner.search_space_summary())
tuner.search(trainX, trainY, epochs=5, validation_data=(testX, testY))
models = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=2)
best_model = models[0]
```

Comment: please format your code properly (no excessive indentation, no unnecessary newlines), ensure to provide all imports and data to make it reproducible

Comment: I think I added all the imports needed. There are more parts to the program. So there are a lot more imports, this is just a section, so there is a chance I missed one needed for this, but I think I got all of them.

Comment: It's still missing some data. The idea of a reproducible example is that we can copy/paste your code and reproduce your issue, which we currently can't.